# Proof related to matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ real matrices such that  $A^2 = I, B^2 = I$ and $(AB)^2 = I$.  Prove that $AB = BA$.

Someone help me with this problem

Comment: You could help yourself by searching.

Answer (score 3):

$I = (AB)^2 = (AB)(AB) = A(BA)B \implies AB = A(A(BA)B)B = (A^2)(BA)(B^2) = BA$

Answer (score 2):

$AB=(AB)^{-1} \iff AB=B^{-1}A^{-1} \iff AB=BA$

Comment: how do AB becomes equal to its inverse

Comment: @AmpatishanArun: Because $(AB)^2=I$. That's the definition of inverse.

Comment: $AB^2=I \iff (AB)^{-1}(AB)^2=AB^{-1}I \iff AB=AB^{-1}$

Comment: okay i got it thanks